# python function and variable

Tags: python, function, variables

I reedited my question due to the lack of clarity. the code below get a random number then checks if it is a new high and records it if it is one. Then after a certain delay (1min) it does the same thing again, starting from the last number of the previous period.

I want to run the same for different frequency so i will have many periods, should i rewrite the code below in function for instance, i could get agregateinfrequency(5min), it will return only the print below (or list)

Hope it makes more sense now.

```
for random_number, current_time,i in generator():
    previous_last_price = mynumber
    mynumber = mynumber + (random_number*0.0001)
    #print (random_number*0.01)
    if mynumber >high_price: #new one
        high_price = mynumber
    if mynumber <low_price: #new one
        low_price = mynumber
    last_price = mynumber

    if keyfunc(current_time,1) != previous_reftime1min: #new one
        print mynumber,",",i, current_time,",", keyfunc(current_time,1),",", previous_reftime1min,",", open_price,",", high_price,",", low_price,",", last_price
        wrtr.writerow([mynumber, i,current_time, keyfunc(current_time,1), previous_reftime1min, open_price, high_price, low_price, last_price])    
        myfile.flush() # whenever you want, and/or
        open_price = previous_last_price
        high_price = mynumber
        low_price = mynumber
        last_price = mynumber
        previous_reftime1min = keyfunc(current_time,1)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What's going on with the indentation...?

Comment: If you need to repeat this computation several times over a range of inputs, that lends itself to the use of a `for` loop.  You can clean up the code and put it into a function call within a for loop, but for a small script that isn't necessarily that important.

Comment: i know that looks stupid but i never understood how to keep the indetation in the website, i click on "code" it says enter the code here, and i paste my code, should i do something else?

Comment: @aestrivex, i am not sure the for loop will work here as i read all numbers coming from the generator without saving them, and myhigh_price represents the current high within the period (here 1min diff in the timestamp)

Comment: so if i want to have the myhigh_price in 5min the only thing i know is it will be higher (or=) than the 1min but i would like to keep everything as independant as i can, that look very bad to recreate another myhigh_price_5min though..

Comment: Can you explain what this code is supposed to do and how you get the inputs?

Comment: @matel it's not too intuitive. The idea is that you paste the code straight from your editor, then highlight it and press the code button. It adds four spaces so that it is interpreted as a code section by markdown. (Rather than click the button then paste)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudocode for a possible structure of the script based on as best I understand what you want it to do.

```
def check_price(random_number,last_price):
  new_price = do_some_logic() #do your logic
  write(new_price) #some abstract code to write your output to a file
  return new_price

price=some_initval
  while True:
    g=get_new_random_number()
    price=check_price(g,price)
    sleep(desired_period)
```

Instead of using a for loop, I am using a while loop here.  My understanding is that you intend to use this program as a continuously running daemon, waking up every minute or so, checking some data (e.g. current prices) and running a calculation.  `while True` ensures that the program will do this repeatedly until you kill it.

Comment: i believe i found my answer, that was difficult to explain, but if i change myhigh_price to a dictionary with the key as frequency it seems it will help me to carry it over. Thanks for the help anyway.